# How to upload a video in a new window like Facebook does?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

When you upload a video to Facebook, it pops up a new window with a loading bar and you can continue using the app normally. How can I do something similar?

Comment: Your question is way too broad, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You should use window.open function in Javascript. or a Form open in a _blank window :) It depends on what you really want to do :)

Here is a little Example:

```
onsubmit="target_popup(this)" as a form attribute
```

and the javascript function should look like:

```
function target_popup(form) {
    window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
    form.target = 'formpopup';
}
```